# Create a Dropdown List using Apps Sript whose dropdown value is the same as the selected cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a Dropdown List using Apps Sript for 1 table as follows:
Cells display:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | XYZ |
| KLM | NHB |

When clicking on the cells on the table, there will be a dropdown list with the corresponding value:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O350.png)

ABC       |  XYZ
*ABC      | *XYZ      <-Dropdown

| KLM      | NHB
*KLM     |  *NHB       <-Dropdown

Can you help me?

I tried it by creating a range for the Dropdown List, but on Google Sheets the Dropdown returns all the values in the range without following the rule of adding 1 * in front of the selected cell value

Sorry, i cant upload img in this post

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: thank you very much, 95% my idea, 
but how to add an (* ) to the left of the value in the dropdown list

Comment: I put an array function above the dropdown. when i choose the value in the dropdown list, the upper range will be corrupted. I have a script to clear content (if error) and array function will return previous value

Comment: About your additional question of `thank you very much, 95% my idea, but how to add an (* ) to the left of the value in the dropdown list`, how about modifying `requireValueInList([c])` to `requireValueInList(["*", c])`? But, if I misunderstood your additional question, I apologize.

Comment: About your new question of `I put an array function above the dropdown. when i choose the value in the dropdown list, the upper range will be corrupted. I have a script to clear content (if error) and array function will return previous value`, I think that this is a new question. By posting it as a new question, users including me can think of it. So, can you post it as a new question? If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: thanks @Tanaike , 100% my idea. My recent comment is an addition to the original question, if you are confused why I did this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `100% my idea. My recent comment is an addition to the original question, if you are confused why I did this.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, can I ask you about the result of my answer to your additional question? And, can I ask you whether you can cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Sorry for my wording and level of English. 100% my idea, its means your answer 100% matches what I was looking for. i just wanted to ask about creating dropdown like the original question. thank you 

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood that your issue was resolved. Sorry for my English skill and thank you for replying, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert all cell values to the dropdown lists including each cell value.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and set your sheet name and save the script.

```js
function sample() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const dataValidations = range.getValues().map(r => r.map(c => SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList([c]).build()));
  range.setDataValidations(dataValidations);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script `sample()` is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the data range is used. If you want to use the specific range, please modify `const range = sheet.getDataRange();` to your actual situation. For example, if you want to use the columns "A" and "B", please modify it to `const range = sheet.getRange("A1:B" + sheet.getLastRow());`

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Class DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)
- [setDataValidations(rules)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationsrules)